# How to Emulate Statement Exprs GNU extension on Standard C++

Tags: c++, c++11, g++

I need to automatically translate from certain language to C++. The source language has the equivalent of [Statement Exprs](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html#Statement-Exprs) and I'm having a lot of difficulty replicating that on standard C++ (C++11, actually).

At first I considered lambdas, but the result is very ugly (with lambdas within lambdas within lambdas...) and possibly would bring the compiler to its knees when applied to large sources.

How could I replicate that GNU extension? It is imperative that semantics about construction/destruction/copying/etc are maintained, so translating this:

```
Foo foo( { ... declarations and statements ... } );
```

into this:

```
Foo foo;
... declarations and statements ...
foo = last result;
```

is not correct (as `Foo` is being constructed with default constructor and then assigned, instead of being constructed with the last value of the block of statements. Also, objects created inside the block of statements have a different lifetime on each case.)

Please note that this question also applies for the case where a program that uses that extension needs to be translated to Standard C++.

Comment: Replace it with a function?

Comment: An immediately evaluated lambda expression?

Comment: ... why do you default-construct `foo` in the first place, then?

Comment: @Mat: a function has no access to variables on the holding function.

Comment: @KerrekSB: As mentioned on the question, I'm afraid that the result of using lambdas will be too convoluted.

Comment: @Xeo: I must replicate the semantics on the original source.

Comment: @user643005: a function can take parameters

Comment: @Mat: determining the parameters that need to be passed and how they must be passed (value, ref, const ref) is hard. Lambdas automatically do that but, as mentioned, the resulting code is read-only. Using functions makes things worse, as it disperses the code, with a medium sized function (on the original source) being translated to dozens of other functions. Making sense of that (for debugging on my translator, or for code maintenance on the case of a GNU -> Standard code conversion) would be a nightmare.

Answer (score 1):

This *might* work:

```
uint8_t foo[sizeof (Foo)];
do {
  /* declarations and statements */
  new (foo) Foo (/*last result*/);
} while (0);
```

Then replace every reference to foo with

```
*((Foo *) foo)
```

Comment: I already considered the foo[sizeof(Foo)] trick for controlling return values (a template class, actually, which also destroys the held object and with an operatorFoo for automatically casting to the correct type in expressions that use foo.) I'm not sure how well this plays with the optimizers, though, and I'm afraid of some other hidden trap. But I still hope that it is a viable solution. As for the do{...} while(0); trick I didn't thought of it and looks promising. Thanks!

Comment: I don't like it. How do you invoke the destructor ?

Comment: I don't think this form should bother the optimizer.  Either way, sizeof (Foo) bytes are stack-allocated (generally, and if not the deciding factor isn't going to be the declared type).  Since every subsequent use of foo is of the correct type, I think you're safe.

Alexandre C: this is a very good point--I'm not sure, to be honest.  Will a destructor ever be called on a reference?

Comment: @JW: no, unless it is the special form `const Foo f& = bar ()` or `Foo&& f = bar ()` with `bar` returning by value. Anyway, when you use placement new, you almost always need to invoke the destructor like `((Foo *) foo)->~Foo ()`.

Comment: If we declared a function like static inline Foo bar(void *foo) { return *((Foo *) foo); } (which would allow us to use that form) I am pretty sure nearly all optimizers would compile it out at -Oanything, but that's entirely speculation.  However, because the initial buffer will be destroyed when the stack frame is popped anyway, any information relevant to destruction is in the value even if it is copied, so I think this would be acceptable.

Comment: Also alignment is a concern here.

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```
Foo foo ([]() -> some_type { blah blah; return last_result; } ());
```

The drawback (outside verbosity) is that you cannot deduce the return type of the lambda, unless everything fits in the return statement. It seems that C++1y will solve this though.

Comment: Curiously enough, neither g++ 4.7.3 nor Clang++ 4.7.3 complains when the lambda's return type is omitted and the body contains several statements.

Answer (score 1):

Lambdas are actually the right translation. They have exactly the semantic you would wish for, after all, and were described as such by Herb Sutter himself in [Complex initialization for a const variable](http://herbsutter.com/2013/04/05/complex-initialization-for-a-const-variable/).

If you do not wish to use lambdas, or cannot afford C++11, another solution is to turn to `boost::optional`:

```
boost::optional<Foo> foo_;
{
    // init computations
    foo_ = Foo(....);
}
Foo& foo = *foo_;
```

Comment: Note: `boost::optional` is just placement new wrapped into some RAII class, to have the destructor called at scope exit (you don't really need the full optional semantics here, only construction and the right alignment).

Comment: @AlexandreC.: I would argue you need quite a bit (after all, were the init computation to fail you need *not* to invoke the destructor); and it just happens it's already available.